# DataGridTextboxcolumn readonly based on condition

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am using c# compact framework. vs 2005. I am binding a datatable to datagrid. I have a placed datagridTEXTBOXCOULUMN as one column of the Datagrid. I need to make that column readonly based on the 
value in the other column.

for eg. If Cid column value is 2, i need to make datagridTEXTBOXCOULUMN  read only true.
If Cid column value is 4, i need to make datagridTEXTBOXCOULUMN  read only false.
this needs to be done on binding the data to datagrid.

Is there any event in which i can do this
i have this property datagridTEXTBOXCOULUMN.readonly

in which event i can do this based on condition

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RowDataBound event of the grid,

```
 protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = e.Row.FindControl("TextBoxID") as TextBox;

            if(<<Your condition>>)
            {
                textBox.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bee the code given is perfect for asp.net. 
but I am using c# compact framework. vs 2005.